# Verify File upload on form submission php

Tags: php, forms

Hi there i'm trying to verify that a file was uploaded by the user before submitting the form.  It simply says files not uploaded every time. This works for text but not files it seems.

HTML

```
<li>
            <label for="uthumb">Image of chair 120 x 200:</label>
            <input type="file" name="uthumb"/>
            <div class="errorAdd"><?php echo $errorThumb; ?></div>
            </li>

             <li>
            <label for="uthumb">Large Image of chair 400 x 500:</label>
            <input type="file" name="ulrgthumb"/>
            <div class="errorAdd"><?php echo $errorImg; ?></div>
            </li>
```

PHP

```
    $newThumb='';
    $newimg='';    

if(empty($_POST['uthumb'])){
            $all_valid = false;

        $errorThumb = 'We need a thumbnail';

    }else{

        $newThumb=$_POST['uthumb'];
    }
if(empty($_POST['ulrgthumb'])){
            $all_valid = false;

        $errorImg = 'We need a large image';

    }else{

        $newimg=$_POST['ulrgthumb'];
    }


}
```

Comment: stealth edit? not sure what you're going on about there? I edited to reflect what I'm being told down below? I actually never really add summary if that's what you mean? And obviously it's wrong why would post a problem if there was no problem. Yes it seems like a simple fix, I wasn't thinking. I was trying the wrong things to fix it. I obviously get that now, and i think the tone of your message is completely unnecessary.

Comment: @moliminous For the sake of people finding this question in future, please do not edit the question to reflect the provided answers. The only time you should edit the question is to fix formatting or add more information.

Comment: @Chris  and the OP surely flagged my comment about their stealth edit http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/36228122/2 as it disappeared from comments. They obviously changed from `$_POST` to `$_Files` which is a syntax error right there and did not mark the edit AS an additional edit.

Comment: Whoever flagged my comment about the OP doing a stealth edit was out of line. It was a valid comment.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Sigh. I really don't understand why a moderator would have removed that or why OP would have flagged your comment. This is pretty stupid.

Comment: @Chris You and me both (*sigh*). Well whoever flagged it and had it removed, was out of line. It's pretty clear as to their revisions what happened and the OP responded with: *"stealth edit? not sure what you're going on about there? I edited to reflect what I'm being told down below?"*. Anyway, they can flag all they want; I know I was right and they should have marked it as an additional edit, rather than overwriting their question/code. *Let them eat (bean) cake*. ;-) and thanks for the rollback :)

Comment: @Fred-ii- You need to chill mate, no one flagged your post, i honestly have no idea what you're talking about stealth edit? I changed the code to reflect what was done below, (which doesn't seem to always work) . I'm not sure if i made some sort of taboo, but you obviously are way to uptight regardless, and need to chill. You simply come off as over toxic, and I think you need to work on that heavily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to check

```
$_FILES
```

Not

```
$_POST
```

http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

```
    $newThumb=''; 
$newimg=''; if(empty($_FILES['uthumb'])){ 
     $all_valid = false; 
     $errorThumb = 'We need a thumbnail'; 
}else{ 
     $newThumb=$_FILES['uthumb'];
 } if(empty($_FILES['ulrgthumb'])){ 
     $all_valid = false;
     $errorImg = 'We need a large image'; 
}else{ 
    $newimg=$_FILES['ulrgthumb'];
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the $_FILES array, not the $_POST array: [File upload](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can even add required to your input field, so they can't submit until they add file

check it here:

> http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp